# Do the different weapon types have hidden properties in Loop Hero?

Tags: loop-hero

I noticed that the Axe consistently has higher base damage than other weapons (except at level 1 where every weapon has a base damage of 4-6), but I'm wondering if there's a "hidden cost" of using that weapon type such as lower attack speed or lower accuracy? Otherwise I'm wondering why would I choose to use, say a Lance that seems to have lower damage than weapons of a similar level. (Unless I get a level 4 Lance while my current weapon is level 2 or something like that, of course)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each wepaon type has a certain guaranteed stat:

[See here](https://loophero.fandom.com/wiki/Warrior%27s_Equipment)

Grey quality items seem to have a tendency to have higher base stats (i.e. dmg for weapons, HP for armor) than higher quality equipment of the same level, but in turn suffer from not having anything but that base stat. This is why axes tend to have high base dmg, they are always grey.

Among the other weapon types, there are also slight differences, e.g. polearm is usually a bit higher, while broken sword is a bit lower, possibly to balance the value of their secondary stat.